# Sending Messages to Microsoft Teams Meeting using Bot

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-teams, botframework

How to send messages to Microsoft Teams Meeting Chat without using any delegated user permissions through a bot?

After joining the group meeting, I am getting ChatId and MessageId as a part of Chat Info, How should I send a message through that without using any delegated user's permission?

Comment: By using he chatid you can send message to meeting chat using [proactive message](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/16.proactive-messages). Please check this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-proactive-messages?tabs=dotnet) for more info?

Comment: @Nikitha-MSFT yes, I have checked that, but it needs the bot pre-installed in the respective chats, but that's not my scenario, I need to send messages completely using my code without users adding a bot to chat. Is there anything available to install bot to Group Chats?

Comment: You can install you app using Graph API. Could you please check this [Installed Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-add-teamsappinstallation?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http)?

Comment: @Nikitha-MSFT My scenario is of Group Chats, not teams or specific users, and there is probably no Graph API available to install bot to Group Chats, can you please check if there is any other way out?

Comment: Currently We don't have the API to install the app to Group. Could you please raise a [user voice](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public-preview/category/182881-developer-platform)?

Comment: So, is there any other way to send a message to the group chat?

Comment: Could you please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-proactive-messages?tabs=dotnet) and [sample code](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/16.proactive-messages). These will help you.

Comment: @Rama-MSFT Hey, I have referred this but for this, the bot is to be installed priorly in Group Chats, which is not possible manually in my case, can you find if we can add the bot to GroupChats using ChatId through any API or programmatically?

Answer (score 2):

Currently this is not possible to add the Bot programmatically using API to the Group Chat.